# Why can you create multiple monitor references to the same process in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Here is an example trace where I'm able to call `erlang:monitor/2` on the same Pid:

```
1> Loop = fun F() -> F() end.
#Fun<erl_eval.30.99386804>
2> Pid = spawn(Loop).
<0.71.0>
3> erlang:monitor(process, Pid).
#Ref<0.2485499597.1470627842.126937>
4> erlang:monitor(process, Pid).
#Ref<0.2485499597.1470627842.126942>
5> erlang:monitor(process, Pid).
#Ref<0.2485499597.1470627842.126947>
```

The expressions returned by instruction #4 and #5 are different than #3, meaning that it is possible to create multiple monitor references between the current process and `Pid`. Is there a practical case where you would need or use multiple monitor references to the same process?

I would expect this to return the same reference (returning a new one would perhaps imply that the old one had failed/crashed), following the same logic that exists for `link/1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you use third party library which does this (basically what OTP `*:call/*` functions does):

```
call(Pid, Request) ->
    call(Pid, Request, ?DEFAULT_TIMEOUT).

call(Pid, Request, Timeout) ->
    MRef = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    Pid ! {call, self(), MRef, Request},
    receive
      {answer, MRef, Result} ->
        erlang:demonitor(Mref, [flush]),
        {ok, Result};
      {'DOWN', MRef, _, _, Info} ->
        {error, Info}
    after Timeout ->
        erlang:demonitor(MRef, [flush]),
        {error, timeout}
    end.
```

and then you use it in your code where you would monitor the same process `Pid` and then call function `call/2,3`.

```
my_fun1(Service) ->
    MRef = erlang:monitor(process, Service),
    ok = check_if_service_runs(MRef),
    my_fun2(Service),
    mind_my_stuf(),
    ok = check_if_service_runs(MRef),
    erlang:demonitor(MRef, [flush]),
    return_some_result().

check_if_service_runs(MRef) ->
    receive
      {'DOWN', MRef, _, _, Info} -> {down, Info}
    after 0 -> ok
    end.

my_fun2(S) -> my_fun3(S).

% and a many layers of other stuff and modules
my_fun3(S) -> call(S, hello).
```

What a nasty surprise it would be if `erlang:monitor/2,3` would always return the same reference and if `erlang:demonitor/1,2` would remove your previous monitor. It would be a source of ugly and unsolvable bugs. You should start to think that there are libraries, other processes, your code is part of a huge system and Erlang was made by experienced people who thought it through. Maintainability is key here.

Comment: Having started to look into OTP I have to confess this did not cross my mind. However, wouldn't cast be a more appropriate example than call since it is asynchronous and it is possible to have multiple pending requests? I think that a process that is executing your implementation of `call/3` can only execute one operation at a time, thus requiring only one monitoring reference. Is this true?
Otherwise, I think I definitely understood how it may be useful. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @goncalotomas: You still didn't get it. The problem is not if it is a call or a cast but in code outside those. You can keep the monitor in your code, or another third party library. In a functional language with immutability, it is custom to make libraries with opaque states, callbacks and so on and those states could contain `MRef`s and keep it as long as they need. You must think bigger. There is biggest functional language commercial project ADX301 for which was Erlang designed and used to with 2 millions lines of code. You must think much bigger.

Comment: @goncalotomas: I have added some more code which I hope helps you understand the issue more. It is very artificial but I hope it helps.

Comment: I think I see it now - there might be several 'layers' of code that `self()` ends up executing that might call `erlang:monitor/2` for the same `Pid`, and in that case you pretty much need a unique reference or otherwise things would become chaotic pretty quickly. I guess that explains it, thanks! Your last code additions helped a lot.